# Show div every 3 seconds using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have these two divs and would like to know how can i display the second (box2) div every 3 seconds.

```
<div id="box1" style="background-color:#0000FF">
     <h3>This is a heading in a div element</h3>

    <p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>
<div id="box2" style="background-color:red">
     <h3>This is a heading in a div element</h3>
```

how can i do this with jquery ?

i created a fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/jRmrp/5/

**Update 1**

The answer given by Khanh TO works but i am wondering what to do when div count is more than 2. it only allows for two.

Comment: Look for `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.

Comment: every 3 second for how long

Comment: Why do you need jQuery to do this?

Comment: @ArunPJohny hey, can you please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195189/jquery-toggle-function-is-not-working-with-hoverwords-sliding-letters-extens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this?

```
setInterval(function(){
     $("#box2").toggle();
    $("#box1").toggle();
},3000);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jRmrp/15/)

Updated with new requirement:

```
var currentIndex = 0;
$(".box:not(:eq("+ currentIndex +"))").hide();

var totalDiv = $(".box").length;

setInterval(function(){
     currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % totalDiv;

    $(".box").hide();
     $(".box").eq(currentIndex).show();

},3000);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jRmrp/14/)

Comment: what can i do when i have more than 2 divs ? lets say 3 divs and each should display and hide one after one with in given time. appreciate if you can show me through fiddler

Comment: Nice solution Khanh +1

Comment: @KhanhTO .toggle() is deprecated. could you please provide a better way to do it. toggle causes me this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195189/jquery-toggle-function-is-not-working-with-hoverwords-sliding-letters-extens

Comment: @mazraara: .toggle is for the first solution. You could try the updated general solution without using toggle.

Comment: @mazraara: or you could try my updated solution 1 without using toggle.

Comment: @mazraara: after reading jQuery docs, I found out that what is deprecated is the toggle event, not toggle function. Could you show me the docs saying toggle function is deprecated?

Comment: @KhanhTO check here http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ and thanks for the first solution.

Comment: @mazraara: that's the toggle event, not the toggle function. toggle function us here http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: @KhanhTO Oppz, my bad. i am sorry about it then. can you help me this pls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195189/jquery-toggle-function-is-not-working-with-hoverwords-sliding-letters-extens

Answer (score 2):

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jRmrp/6/)

```
doBoxBlink = setInterval(blink, 1500);

function blink() {
    $('#box2').toggle();
}
```